# Why would two triangles with exact same lengths have the exact same 3 angles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

I know how incredibly stupid this question sounds, and I know any 2 triangles you draw with same line lengths will have the same 3 angles, but I just can't figure out the exact reason why having 3 lines of the same, or congruent, lengths, would lead to 2 triangles having the same angles. Can someone please explain?

Comment: [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

Comment: It's not stupid to question intuition. It helps you have an open mind.

Comment: My question about this, however, is does the law of cosines rely on the property above to be true? Because if it does, that doesn't prove anything. That would be circular.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Constructing a triangle from circles]

No matter what, in order for $a$ to be the same length, point $C$ must fall on circle $d$.  And no matter what, in order for $b$ to be the same length, point $C$ must fall on circle $e$.

With these restrictions, the only choices for $C$ are the two points where the circles intersect.  And these choices differ only by being mirror images of each other, which doesn't change angles, only their winding.

Comment: And distinct circles cannot intersect in more than two places as three points determine a (circum-)circle

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable accepting the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), that provides one explanation.  This theorem states that, if a triangle has sides with lengths $a, b$, and $c$ whose opposing angle measures are $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$ respectively, then the following relation holds:

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(\gamma)$$

Of course, we can arrive at two similar equations since there are $3$ different ways to label the sides with those letters and whichever way we choose is arbitrary.  For instance, we also have:

$$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2ac \cos(\beta)$$

Looking at the first, notice that we can solve for $\cos(\gamma)$ in terms of the side lengths.  Because $\cos:(0,\pi) \rightarrow [-1,1]$ is an [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) function, the value of $\cos(\gamma)$ determines $\gamma$ itself.  To be explicit:

$$\gamma = \arccos \left( \frac{c^2 - a^2 - b^2}{-2ab} \right)$$

And we have similar equations for angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: My question about this, however, is does the law of cosines rely on the property above to be true? Because if it does, that doesn't prove anything. That would be circular.

Comment: @EthanChan, that is definitely a good thing to be concerned about.  But it turns out we can prove it without needing SSS congruence.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Using_the_distance_formula

Answer (score 1):

Given three lengths $a,b,c$ such that $a+b\ge c$, $a+c\ge b$ and $b+c\ge a$ we can construct the triangle uniquely up to rotation, translation and reflection: Draw points $A,B$ at distance $c$ connected by a line segment. The third point $C$ must have distance $a$ from $B$ and distance $b$ from $A$. Hence, it is an intersection point of the circle around $A$ with radius $b$ and the circle around $B$ with radius $a$. There are exactly two such points and the resulting triangles are mirror images of each other. The only choices here were where to put the line segment $AB$ and which of the two intersection points you choose. None of these choices influence the angles of the triangles.